# T-SQL Data type for fixed precision and variable scale

Tags: t-sql, types

I have a set of data with a precision of 16 digits, however this can range from very large numbers with all 16 digits to the left of the decimal point to very small number with all digits to right of the decimal point.  (e.g. 1234567890123456.0 & 0.1234567890123456 )  I am trying to figure out the correct ("best") data type to store this data in.  I need to store the exact values and not an approximations so float & real are not viable options.  Numeric or decimal seem appropriate, however I am getting hung up on the most efficient precision & scale to set, it seems I must go with (32,16) to account for both extremes, but that seem inefficient as I am requesting twice the bit storage that I will ever use.  Is there a better option?

Thank You for your assistance.

Comment: You could go with two columns, a `biging` for all the digits disregarding the decimal dot and a `tinyint` to store the power of 10 to divide it by. 9 bytes instead of 17.

Comment: You may be worrying about [premature optimization](http://xkcd.com/1691/). If you need to store large sets of data (billions) or are running in a constrained environment (IoT night light) then counting bits may be a concern. I/O bandwidth may also an issue for bitwise inefficient representations. You may want to consider how you will be using the data and whether the chosen representation will make that practical first, e.g. is there support for doing arithmetic with the data. That's a _yes_ for `numeric` and _DIY_ for a multi-column construct.